# possible to get emacs to ignore comments during paragraph fill in latex-mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp

When editing LaTeX in emacs, one can have comments in the middle of a paragraph:

```
Line 1
% comment
Line 2
```

Unfortunately if you run `fill-paragraph` while the cursor is on `Line 2`, you get:

```
Line 1
% comment Line 2
```

This makes it quite unusable because now `Line 2` has disappeared from the document.  How can I get emacs to treat `Line 1` and `Line 2` as if they need to be paragraph-filled, but not pile up `Line 2` onto the commented line?

Bonus points if `fill-paragraph` is also run on the commented section.

Comment: Which latex mode are you using? I can't seem to reproduce this in auctex. Also, you might have gotten a bigger audience on [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Running Emacs as packaged by Ubuntu (version 23.1+1-4ubuntu7.2+maverick1), I see this problem if I launch emacs with some file that's not tex, and then open the .tex file later. However, if I open the file directly from the command line, or close all other buffers before finding the tex file, it works fine. Really odd behavior.

Comment: Also on Tex.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131774/how-can-i-tell-emacs-to-correctly-fill-around-latex-comments

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually in LaTeX mode?

The only emacs I have to hand right now is 21.2.1, as installed with Cygwin, but if I try

```
Line 1
% a comment
Line 2
Line 3
```

in LaTeX mode hitting Esc-Q (or Esc-X fill-paragraph) gives me

```
Line 1
% a comment
Line 2 Line 3
```

However, if I do Esc-X text-mode and repeat (Esc-q or Esc-X fill-paragraph) I get

```
Line 1 % a comment Line 2 Line 3
```

In other words, emacs deals with a LaTeX comment correctly if it is in the correct mode, but (unsurprisingly) not if it's treating the document as ordinary text

Answer (score 0):

i don't generally edit latex documents, but i don't see the behavior you describe (i opened up a blank doc in emacs 23 and enabled latex-mode).  i pasted in your example, and couldn't get it to fill Line 2 into the comment.  do you possibly have some mode hooks which are breaking the default latex mode values for `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  Installing auctex solved the problem